# Filling an array of struct with inputs from csv file

Tags: c, arrays, file, struct

I have to read this kind of csv file

```
565;4;6;8;11/10/2017;11:30
756;5;9;1;12/12/2017;10:40
765;-8;-2;-1;06/01/2018;23:23
```

And i need to put those datas into this struct

```
typedef struct  {
int cod_event;
int x;
int y;
int z;
int day;
int month;
int year;
int hour;
int minute;
}Eventi_astronomici;
```

This is the array initialized and reallocated with proper dimensions.
So i know the dimension of my file, i just need to fill this array with those integers

```
    Eventi_astronomici *all_data_astro;
all_data_astro = calloc(  200  , sizeof(Eventi_astronomici));

if (all_data_astro == NULL)
{
   printf("Malloc failed1!\n");
   return -1;
}
char c;
for (c = getc(file_ptr); c != EOF; c = getc(file_ptr))
    if (c == '\n') // Increment count if this character is newline 
        count = count + 1; 



printf("%d\n", count);

all_data_astro =  realloc( all_data_astro , count * sizeof( Eventi_astronomici));

if (all_data_astro == NULL)
{
   printf("Realloc failed!\n");
   return -1;
}
```

Thats what im trying for taking inputs from file, before that i rewind the file ptr. Then i print my array to see if fscanf worked

```
for( i = 0 ; i < count ; i++){
    fscanf(file_ptr , "%d;%d;%d;%d;%d/%d/%d;%d:%d" ,&all_data_astro[i].cod_event, &all_data_astro[i].x ,
        &all_data_astro[i].y,&all_data_astro[i].z,&all_data_astro[i].day ,
            &all_data_astro[i].month,&all_data_astro[i].year,&all_data_astro[i].hour,&all_data_astro[i].minute );
}



for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        printf("%d,%d,%d,%d,%d/%d/%d,%d:%d\n",all_data_astro[i].cod_event, all_data_astro[i].x ,
            all_data_astro[i].y,all_data_astro[i].z,all_data_astro[i].day ,
                all_data_astro[i].month,all_data_astro[i].year,all_data_astro[i].hour,all_data_astro[i].minute);

    }
```

tho its strange that even if fscanf doesnt work i dont get any print. So the program probably blocks before even reaching the next for cycle, maybe i need to check for fscanf return value in an if?

Comment: ye i did , tho im not used to this kind of file indenting and so im probably failing with fscanf, but i dont know to do it

Comment: @xing it seems definitely better to just calloc once, thats nice.  if i give "%d;%d;%d;%d;%d/%d/%d;%d:%d" to fscanf , when it compiles ,the program freezes after giving me back my count value and then ends after few seconds.

Comment: Ok i finally solved my problems, thank u mister xing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another approach would be to read a line using `fgets`, realloc for each line and parse the line using `sscanf`. For large numbers of lines, realloc could be done for blocks of lines and keep track of the number of lines allocated and the lines used. Allocating again when the number of used lines equals the number allocated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct  {
    int cod_event;
    int x;
    int y;
    int z;
    int day;
    int month;
    int year;
    int hour;
    int minute;
}Eventi_astronomici;

int main ( void) {
    char line[100] = "";
    int count = 0;
    int each = 0;
    FILE *pf = NULL;
    Eventi_astronomici *all_data_astro = NULL;
    Eventi_astronomici *temp = NULL;

    if ( NULL == ( pf = fopen ( "astrodata.txt", "r"))) {
        fprintf ( stderr, "could not open file\n");
        return 0;
    }

    while ( fgets ( line, sizeof line, pf)) {
        if ( NULL == ( temp = realloc ( all_data_astro, sizeof ( *all_data_astro) * (count + 1)))) {
            fprintf ( stderr, "realloc problem\n");
            fclose ( pf);
            free ( all_data_astro);
            return 0;
        }
        all_data_astro = temp;
        if ( 9 == sscanf ( line, "%d;%d;%d;%d;%d/%d/%d;%d:%d"
        , &all_data_astro[count].cod_event
        , &all_data_astro[count].x
        , &all_data_astro[count].y
        , &all_data_astro[count].z
        , &all_data_astro[count].day
        , &all_data_astro[count].month
        , &all_data_astro[count].year
        , &all_data_astro[count].hour
        , &all_data_astro[count].minute )) {
            count++;
        }
        else {
            printf ( "problem with record\n");
        }
    }

    fclose ( pf);

    for ( each = 0; each < count; ++each) {
        printf("%d,%d,%d,%d,%d/%d/%d,%d:%d\n"
        , all_data_astro[each].cod_event
        , all_data_astro[each].x
        , all_data_astro[each].y
        , all_data_astro[each].z
        , all_data_astro[each].day
        , all_data_astro[each].month
        , all_data_astro[each].year
        , all_data_astro[each].hour
        , all_data_astro[each].minute);
    }

    free ( all_data_astro);

    return 0;
}
```